# easy_curl_perform returns error 26 (write error)

Tags: c++, curl

Callback:

```
static size_t w_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
#ifdef DBG
    add_debug("Curl callback is called from pastebin");
#endif
    pastebin_ret_data = ptr;    
    return CURLE_OK;
}
```

Main:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, (void*)1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (void*)api_url_u8.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, &curl_err_buf[0]);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, (void*)w_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (void*)postfields_u8.c_str());
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);  // blocking file transfer
#ifdef DBG
    add_debug("easy_perform result: " + std::to_string(res) + 
              " error msg: " + &curl_err_buf[0] );
#endif
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Debug:
Curl callback is called from pastebin
Time: Wed Dec 24 09:47:44 2014

easy_perform result: 23 error msg: Failed writing body (0 != 30)

What is the problem?

Comment: Notice that return-type of the callback function? It's `size_t` which should tell you that the function should return a size and not just a status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return CURLE_OK instead of returning the number of bytes you processed.

CURLE_OK is defined as 0, and that is the value you return. The number of processed bytes by you in the callback function must equal to the number received by the function arguments: `size_t size, size_t nmemb` and that is the value you must return.

Documentation says: *Your callback should return the number of bytes actually taken care of. If that amount differs from the amount passed to your callback function, it'll signal an error condition to the library. This will cause the transfer to get aborted and the libcurl function used will return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR.*

The value of CURLE_WRITE_ERROR is 23.

I also noticed the last argument to these curl_easy_setopt are not correct:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, (void*)1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (void*)api_url_u8.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, (void*)w_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (void*)postfields_u8.c_str());
```

The types you pass are correct given the parameter type. The void* casts should not be there.